# issues with CF query of queries with new patch on coldfusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I did a recent update on coldfusion 11 to latest patch. Before the patch, the following code was working perfectly fine, but after the update I am getting the following error. Please note the columns I am outputting has nothing related with date

> Query Of Queries runtime error.
> Type cast exception: Failed to cast object of type java.lang.String to java.util.Date.

```
<cfset QueryAddColumn(data,"IsaString",ArrayNew(1))>
<cfloop query="data">
    <cfset querySetCell(data, "IsaString", "YES", data.currentRow) />
</cfloop>
<cfquery name="getCustomersbasedContacts" dbtype="query">
    SELECT CAST(contact_id as varchar) + '~' + CAST(IsaString as varchar) + '~' + CAST(contact_name as varchar) as id,
    contact_name + '-' + email as text
    FROM data
    where status = 'active'
</cfquery>
```

where `data` represents a query

Comment: So what have you done to troubleshoot the issue? If you have not tried anything, start with the concatenation.  Start with a single cast + and add the columns back one at a time.

Comment: i added cast to the remaining elements rather than the first one, but i am not sure if there is no date, why it is going to date, seems like a bug

Comment: That is not what I suggested. Start with a single column, ie `SELECT Cast(...)`. Then add back the next column, and so on, to see which part is causing it to break. Though it raises the question of why do this within a QoQ, instead of the original db query?

Comment: Try using `||` instead of `+` as a concatenation operator.